# Threading with PERL in Irssi

Tags: multithreading, perl, irssi

The thread module for PERL does not seem to work with Irssi.
I can't get more information on this because the folk at #Irssi never respond.

I need to have the script check a database every 5 minutes.
Now I thought this would be possible with multi-threading in PERL, but once you include the module Irssi will thrown an Exception.

Ironically, if I try and construct a while loop that terminates itself after a set amount of time the Irssi client just hangs.

Any suggestions?

Code

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use threads;
    use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();    # A new empty queue
    # Worker thread
    my $thr = threads->create(
        sub {
            # Thread will loop until no more work
            while (defined(my $item = $q->dequeue())) {
                # Do work on $item
            }
        }
    );
```

Errors in Irssi (not all of them, but same thing, cant locate package):

```
13:30| Can't locate package Irssi::ServerSetup for
          @Irssi::Irc::ServerSetup::ISA at
          /home/nullby7e/.irssi/scripts/test.pl line 27.
13:30|
13:30| Can't locate package Irssi::Nick for @Irssi::Irc::Nick::ISA at
          /home/nullby7e/.irssi/scripts/test.pl line 27.
13:30|
13:30| Can't locate package Irssi::ServerConnect for
          @Irssi::Irc::ServerConnect::ISA at
          /home/nullby7e/.irssi/scripts/test.pl line 27.
```

Comment: I don't think Perl threading is ever going to work with the irssi application.  But CPAN has irssi modules for both POE and AnyEvent--that approach would be much more likely to work, did you look into that?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, will look into that.

Comment: may be use the fork command?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with threads, but according to [Irssi Perl Scripting Reference](http://www.irssi.org/documentation/perl) you want the `Irssi::timeout_add` function.

You can find many examples how to use it at [Irssi's Script Repository](http://scripts.irssi.org/). Basic usage is:

```
use Irssi;

sub check_database {
    ...
}

Irssi::timeout_add(5*60*1000, "check_database", undef);
```